# notepad++ NppExec - complete list of all internal commands?

Tags: command-line, notepad++, editor, document

For notepad++ plugin NppExec, there are many internal commands like NPP_SAVE, SEL_SAVETO.

There are many examples using various internal commands in help file.

But the complete list of internal commands does not exist in help file.

Where is the complete list of internal commands of NppExec?

Comment: Likely [this file](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/blob/master/NppExec/doc/NppExec/NppExec.txt) ?

Comment: It is strange that help .chm file does not contain this information.

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive one does not exist to my knowledge.  It's complicated by the fact that Notepad++ has its own commands, Scintilla commands, Plugins, and various extensions that the user can add.

**This [Quick Reference](https://mathscitech.org/articles/computing-toolkits/npp#appendix-internals) may be of some help.**

If you need more, put in the comments, or drop me a mail, and I can elaborate this answer or add detail to the posting.